# How to check security default is enabled or diabled using azure rest api?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rest-api

I want to check status (enabled / disabled) of security default for azure active directory using rest ? I am not able to find exact rest API.

Answer (score 1):

This property can be accessed via backend Azure AD APIs (which are behind portal.azure.com). You can check status of `SecurityDefaults` using below API -

```
https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/SecurityDefaults/GetSecurityDefaultStatus
```

To consume above API you need to pass proper `Authorization` & `x-ms-client-request-id` values via header.

For how you can check these APIs which are behind portal please refer [here](https://goodworkaround.com/2020/11/27/accessing-the-backend-azure-ad-apis-behind-portal-azure-com/).